# "Scouring the globe", literal origins?

Tags: etymology

In their *Curious Objects* exhibition Cambridge University Library's *English Globe* (of 1585-ish) came with an annual maintenance bill which included its scouring, which seems to have involved reapplication of new varnish. Is this practice (in general, among owners of globes) an etymological origin for the corresponding metaphorical phrase *scouring the globe/earth*, or a coincidence?

Comment: Nope. The "search for something" sense of *scour* [dates back to the 1300s](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scour&allowed_in_frame=0), and likely arose from a borrowing from  Old Norse *skyra* "rush in" (and is related to *shower*, as there was a related word in ON meaning "incoming missiles", ultimately from "rain"). The "rub vigorously to remove a coating" sense is a mere century older. Both of these predate widespread use of globes; [the earliest extant terrestrial globe dates back to 1492](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globe#History), though there is evidence of earlier globes.

Comment: And, a caveat for future etymological questions: in my experience, the more interesting or "narrative" a proposed etymology is, the less likely it is to be true. This is how folk etymologies get their start and derive their staying power, by being more interesting than the dull "Nah, it was imported from the Vikings centuries before globes were used".

Comment: I think I was reasonably careful to pose it as a question!

Comment: No, no, you certainly did. I wasn't chiding you. I was putting up a big "warning" sign so you don't fall into traps, as folk etymologies, yours or someone else's, have a strangely persuasive allure. Listen not to their siren songs. Look ye among the dusty tomes no one wishes to read.

Comment: The full OED's first citation for ***scour** = to range about in search of something* is 1297, at which time there were hardly any *Anglophones* (certainly most of us today would barely recognise what was spoken then as "English"), let alone people who believed the world was a *globe*. I think the premise of this question is frankly ridiculous.

Comment: I think it was a very good question because it is so specific in terms of where the OP saw the meaning where it meant varnish. And then wonders about a general meaning. Unfortunately, the OED costs 300 dollars a year so not all of us can afford it. They should have a special rate for language professionals but unfortunately do not.

Comment: @Lambie You don't need the OED for etymologies. See the first comment under the question, and the links I included in it. There are many free resources to find etymologies. Not just etymonline, which is my favorite, but any dictionary. OED just happens to be the 800 pound gorilla. But for most situations a 200 pound gorilla will do.

Comment: @Lambie: In the UK at least, most of us can get free access to the full OED through our library card number. But it costs nothing to follow Dan's etymonline link above, which contains much the same information.

Comment: @Dan: (Or "a 160-lb Dan", assuming you're not overweight! :)

Comment: @Lambie Here (stateside) too many libraries have it but it can only be used "in-house". There may be many free sources for etymology but the OED is the gold standard.

Comment: @Lambie As I said, the "gold standard" is nice to have, but rarely necessary. The other options are sufficient for this case, and most cases like it. OP could have used them to dispositively determine the answer to his question was "no". Incidentally, here in NYC we get free online access to the OED with our library card numbers. I don't prefer the OED because its format is still too strongly influenced by its historical, paper, constraints, and thus is inconvenient to use. (Plus the site is dog slow. Like, bad.)

Comment: @Dan Bron So glad to know that living in NYC provides some benefit (I never could derive any benefit from living there). Those constraints do not bother me. I guess a site with 750,000 words (or something like that) would be  unwieldly....

Comment: I would certainly have looked in an OED if I'd had a copy. I used to have access (but not own) one of those giant volumes of n-to-a-page and a magnifying glass, but no more, and used it all the time. I did have a google beforehand, and looked in a couple of online dictionaries with etymologies (which suggested a "rush" etymology, but it wasn't clear to me that this would be the origin as used in the phrase). Tbh, it doesn't seem any more ridiculous that it should have a literal origin than "eat umble pie" or that "brass monkeys" were actually monkeys made of brass.

Comment: As seems to be the story of my life, I am the only one who has missed the boat here: why should the application of varnish have lent its name to searching? Is the (contested) idea that someone applying varnish had to look what he was doing, so that the word that referred to applying varnish came to refer to looking?

Answer (score 1):

When I hear the term 'scour', I think first of scrubbing (eg 'scouring pads'). The German 'scheuern' is related and also means scrub. To scour a globe likely included scrubbing it before varnishing.

To 'scour the globe' is something like to 'comb the globe', both implying thorough inspection or treatment.

I imagine the semantic similarity between the processes of scrubbing and of searching meticulously is the origin of the phrase 'to scour the globe', just like 'to comb the globe'.

I don't think we can disprove your proposed etymology, but I think mine is more likely.

Comment: This is the way I've always interpreted it.  The act of searching for something is often described as "scouring" -- one might scour the house for that missing shoe.  "Scouring the globe" is just a bit of dramatic overstatement.

Comment: We can disprove it from the actual established etymology by paid professional lexicographers which I quoted in my first comment under the question. *Scour* has been attested in this sense since the 14th century at the latest, and derives from an Old Norse word meaning "to rush in", and the related meaning of "scrub something clean" is actually *newer*, by a century, than the "search vigorously" sense. So no, both your an OP's proposed etymologies are denied by the facts.

Comment: I'm vehement about this because the Internet is already creating a "post truth" problem, and we don't need to be adding more fuel to that fire with yet more folk etymologies, misattributed quotes, "revised" histories, or "alternative facts". Though given the disease has already infected the highest offices of my nation, I might have to give up my campaign :/

Comment: The etymology at etymonline for scour states that its meaning may have been influenced by the meaning to polish or clean (to scrub). The facts are far from clear here. Multiple hypotheses are possible, truth on this matter is something neither you nor I were able to find in our sources.